# Bolzano--Weierstrass Theorem implies Nested Interval Property

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

This question is from abbott's Understanding Analysis:

> Start with the Bolzano--Weierstrass Theorem and use it to 
>   construct a proof of the Nested Interval Property.

**My try:** Let $I_n=[a_n,b_n]$ be closed intervals such that $I_1 \supseteq I_2 \supseteq \dots$. So here $a_n$ is a (nondecreasing) bounded sequence, so it contains a convergent subsequence by hypothesis, so does $b_n$.

But here I am stuck. I have temptation to use Monotone Convergence Theorem, but that would imply that I am assuming Axiom of Completeness, or worse, Nested Interval Property itself!

Comment: The Axiom of spremum must be taken as a starting point.

Comment: The Bolzano-Weierstrass recursion build the intervals that you want. Construct with every choice of the Bolzano-Weierstrass the intervals.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you noted, there is a subsequence $n_k$  such that $a_{n_k}\to a$.  As $I_n$ is closed and contains almost all $a_{n_k}$, we have $a\in I_n$. As this holds for all $n$, $a\in\bigcap I_n$